# Choose Device to run on for calabash-ios

Tags: objective-c, cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios

How can I choose which device to run `cucumber` on with `calabash-ios`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to run calabash-ios on real devices you need to set a couple of environment variables

```
BUNDLE_ID=com.bundle.id.for.your.app DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://192.168.1.111:37265 calabash-ios console your_app.ipa
```

this would open the calabash console.  Using the command start_test_server_in_background will open the app (which has to already be installed on your device).

You need the bundle id set so calabash knows which app to open.  You need the DEVICE_ENDPOINT set to the wifi address of the device so that calabash knows how to interact with the app once it's open.

If you want to run calabash on a simulator then fabb's answer should cover it.

Edited to fix the http endpoint as per comment from @jmoody

Comment: Just realised that you answered your own question!  I'll leave my answer in case it's useful to anyone.

Comment: Yes, but I just answered it for simulators. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

For running on a specific simulator, just set the `DEVICE_TARGET` env var when starting `cucumber`.

To find out which devices are available, you can execute `instruments -s devices` in terminal.

In my project, I run `cucumber` twice, once for iPad and once for iPhone. I do it the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

cd ${0%/*}/..

: ${APP_BUNDLE_PATH:?"Need to set APP_BUNDLE_PATH"}

export DEBUG=1

SCREENSHOT_PATH_IPHONE=`pwd`/calabash_screenshots/iphone/
SCREENSHOT_PATH_IPAD=`pwd`/calabash_screenshots/ipad/

mkdir -p ${SCREENSHOT_PATH_IPHONE}
mkdir -p ${SCREENSHOT_PATH_IPAD}

export RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS=1 

SCREENSHOT_PATH=${SCREENSHOT_PATH_IPHONE} DEVICE_TARGET="iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)" bundle exec cucumber --tags @ios_phone -p ios
SCREENSHOT_PATH=${SCREENSHOT_PATH_IPAD} DEVICE_TARGET="iPad Retina (8.1 Simulator)" bundle exec cucumber --tags @ios_tablet -p ios
```

Note that this depends on a [cucumber.yml](https://github.com/calabash/x-platform-example/blob/master/config/cucumber.yml) and according tags `@ios_phone` and `@ios_tablet` being set in the feature files.